# How to run temporary effect when data changes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know React compares old DOM with newer DOM and replaces only changed HTML elements but how can I detect them in a similar to *MutationObserver* so that I can run an effect?

For example:

Some data is returned by an API:

```js
[
 {id: 1, ticker: "STAK", price: "30"},
 {id: 2, ticker: "OVER", price: "40"},
 {id: 3, ticker: "FLOW", price: "50"}
]
```

It's the rendered to the page like this:

```
<div>STAK Price : <span>30</span></div>
<div>OVER Price : <span>40</span></div>
<div>FLOW Price : <span>50</span></div>
```

The data is refetched after an interval and it now looks like this

```js
[
 {id: 1, ticker: "STAK", price: "30"},
 {id: 2, ticker: "OVER", price: "60"},
 {id: 3, ticker: "FLOW", price: "50"}
]
```

```
 <div>STAK Price : <span>30</span></div>
 <div>OVER Price : <span>60</span></div> // OVER's Price is Changed
 <div>FLOW Price : <span>50</span></div>
```

How can I add a class to the `span` around `OVER`'s price to run a CSS effect then remove it after 2 seconds?

Comment: Can you describe how you use these divs, is each div a separate component or are all the divs grouped into one component? If each div is a component, you can simply use  useEffect.

Comment: @ZouhairDre Like the Example, Maybe There are so many Stock Price Objects.. (maybe over 60~70) Is it tolerable for make component for each object?

Comment: If you use a separate component for each div you logic inside the useEffect will be like
//change css 
setTimeOut(()=>{/*remove div*/},60000);
if you warp all the divs in one component, you will have to add a flag updated for example to each div, and based on its value you can call a function to....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React gives you a function to react to changes in data with an effect: the [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). The first argument takes a function with the effect you want to happen and the second argument takes an array of variables that when changed between calls of the hook React will run the effect.

So we currently know we can use `useEffect` to run an effect for a certain amount of time when *variable* has changed. It might look like this:

```
·  useEffect(() => {
·    runEffect();
·  
·    setTimeout(() => {
·      stopEffect();
·    }, time);
·  }, [variable]);
```

This does have a problem where the effect is run on the initial render (which is likely unwanted behaviour) so we'll need to detect if this is the first render:

```
+  const firstRender = useRef(true);
+  
·  useEffect(() => {
+    if (firstRender.current) {
+      return;
+    }
+  
·    runEffect();
·  
·    setTimeout(() => {
·      stopEffect();
·    }, time);
·  }, [variable]);
+ 
+  useEffect(() => {
+    if (firstRender.current) {
+      firstRender.current = false;
+    }
+  });
```

Now for running and stopping the effect. We could return a piece of data to say whether the variable has recently changed, perhaps a variable named `hasRecentlyChanged`. The component could then react to this change in data and update the representation of the view. Doing this will also allow us to encapsulate this logic into a custom hook and separate the concerns of detecting recent changes from the effect the component runs:

```
function useHasRecentlyChanged(variable, timeout = 2000) {
  const firstRender = useRef(true);
  const [hasRecentlyChanged, setHasRecentlyChanged] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      return;
    }

    setHasRecentlyChanged(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setHasRecentlyChanged(false);
    }, timeout);
  }, [variable]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false;
    }
  });

  return hasRecentlyChanged;
}
```

In your case, you'd likely call this hook in a component that encapsulates an individual ticker.

Below, I've created a demo which updates a list of random numbers (min 0, max 1000) every 5 seconds. Items that change will get a rainbow effect applied to the text for 2 seconds.

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

function useHasRecentlyChanged(variable, timeout = 2000) {
  const firstRender = useRef(true);
  const [hasRecentlyChanged, setHasRecentlyChanged] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      return;
    }
  
    setHasRecentlyChanged(true);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      setHasRecentlyChanged(false);
    }, timeout);
  }, [variable]);
   
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false;
    }
  });
  
  return hasRecentlyChanged;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  const ceilMin = Math.ceil(min);
  const floorMax = Math.floor(max);

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (floorMax - ceilMin + 1)) + ceilMin;
}

function ListItem({ key, children }) {
  const hasRecentlyChanged = useHasRecentlyChanged(children);
  
  return (
    <li key={key} className={hasRecentlyChanged ? 'changed' : undefined}>{children}</li>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
    getRandomInt(0, 1000),
  ]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => { 
      const newItems = [...items];
      const updateIndex = getRandomInt(0, items.length - 1);
      newItems[updateIndex] = getRandomInt(0, 1000);
      setItems(newItems);
    }, 5000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [...items]);
 
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => <ListItem key={index}>{item}</ListItem>)}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.changed {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red, violet);
  background-size: 800% 800%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: rainbow 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes rainbow { 
  0% {background-position: 0% 50% }
  50% {background-position: 100% 25% }
  100% {background-position: 0% 50% }
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry for another Question, but How can I check if old value is smaller or bigger? I just want to make difference as adding different class for diffrent css Effect. (When new Value is bigger, effects Red Flickering or Smaller then Blue Flickering). It seems  `props.children` has only present value

Comment: Would you consider posting a new question? The comment box is a bit too small to get all the context for a question and also too small to write substantial answers. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116456/react-js-add-class-by-detecting-element-value-change This is my New Question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### **`MutationObserver`  or you can use `DOMSubtreeModified`**

**Like so:**

```
document
  .querySelector("#value")
  .addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    alert("value changed");
  });
```

**Working code snippet:**

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(["Banana", "Watermelon", "Pear"]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
document
  .querySelector("#list")
  .addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    alert("element changed");
  });
  }, []);

  const handleChangeState = () => {
setState(["Banana", "Watermelon", "Cherry"]);
  };

  return (
<div className="App">
  <button type="button" onClick={handleChangeState}>
    Change State
  </button>
  <ul id="list">
    {state.map((item) => (
      <li>{item}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: so Is there no way for using React Hooks?
React is for catching changed DOM element though, should I use *MutationObserver* or *DOMSubtreeModified*?

Comment: Yes, you can turn the `document.querySelector` part to a hook or a helper as you prefer. For me, `DOMSubtreeModified` is more reliable than the other one.

Comment: You could consider marking this answer as accepted if you find it useful and highlight it for others who need it.